# Authentication and Authorization in a product ecosystem

Tags: angularjs, node.js, security, authentication, authorization

I have a product ecosystem consisting of multiple products i.e: An angular app, a website and a hybrid app all powered by node back end.

So, now I want to add a single authentication and authorization to the whole ecosystem also it needs to be modular and scalable.

Plus I'm following a 3-tier architecture i.e: **[APPLICATION] --> [API] --> [DB]**, only the API layer having access to the DB.

Now I also want the Authentication and Authorization to be **another app** in the ecosystem that can be plugged into other apps and used without much setup.

Also since It's(Authentication and Authorization module) another application I don't want it to access the DB directly, I want it to make API calls that do it, plus it shouldn't use third party auth schemes like auth0.

Important thing being none of the applications other than the Authentication and Authorization module should have any auth related logic in them.

Basically this should be the module than when plugged in allows Authentication and Authorization and integrates seamlessly.

Is this setup possible? If so how do i go about it? If not how is Authentication and Authorization achieved in other such production grade ecosystems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Authentication can definitely be thought of as a module; just a widget with a database backend that takes in credentials and spits outs error messages or authorization tokens. Authorization, however, is a bit more complicated; once you have received those authorization tokens, you need to decide what they mean.

Without knowing anything about your applications, I would say that you would need to create a mapping of privileges to user accounts for each application. This is trivial if you just want to restrict users from accessing each other's content, but gets harder if you want to give some users more (or less) power than others. If that is the case, than I'd suggest you use some form of [role-based access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control). You can find some more discussion on how to handle authorization [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37850/role-vs-identity-based-authentication-what-is-the-difference).